# Как найти подстроку через CrudRepository

Tags: java, mysql, crud

Необходимо написать метод, который ищет содержание заданной подстроки в поле. Если использовать просто findByContent (к примеру) то ищется полное совпадение, когда как в моем случае, необходимо найти contains а не equals.

```
public interface EntryRepo extends CrudRepository<Entry, Integer> {
List<Entry> findByContent(String content);
List<Entry> findByTitle(String title);
List<Entry> findById(int id);
```

}

Comment: Написать нативный запрос используя ilike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы используете Spring Data JPA, то для создания нужного вам запроса из имени метода, нужно использовать такие ключевые слова как `StartingWith`, `EndingWith` и `Containing`. Т.е. ваш метод будет следующим:

```
List<Entry> findByContentContaining(String partOfContent);
```

`StartingWith` соответствует SQL `where content like partOfContent%`

`EndingWith` соответствует SQL `where content like %partOfContent`

`Containing` соответствует SQL `where content like %partOfContent%`

У Spring хорошая документация и обо всех ключевых словах для создания запросов из методов вы можете узнать из [документации](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation). Гуглить одно из самых важных умений программиста =)

Comment: Для меня не совсем было очевидно, как это нужно гуглить. Containing идеально подошел к моим задачам, за что Вам спасибо!

Comment: Понимаю, сам был в подобных ситуациях. Я приложил, ссылку на документацию, там вы сможете ознакомиться подробнее с деталями создания запросов из имён методов в Spring Data JPA.

Answer (score 0):

Напишите свой запрос

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE name LIKE %:key% OR desc LIKE %:key%", nativeQuery = true)
List<Entry> findByKeyword(@Param("key") String key);
```

Что то в этом духе